# Mount btrfs filesystem on Ubuntu filesystem

Tags: mount, btrfs, fedora

I have next problem - I installed first Fedora on nvme-ssd. Then Ubuntu on usual ssd on same PC.

Now I neither can access Fedora (even if I switch off Ubuntu ssd completely, seems it messed MBR), neither Fedora file system isn't seen from Ubuntu.

Gparted sees it as /dev/nvme-something. How can I mount btrfs-based Fedora file system on Ubuntu?

Comment: You just asked this 1 hour ago. Please do not keep asking the same question.

Comment: It's not the same question. It's the question, how can I mount btrfs system on Ubuntu. My last question was how can I repair Grub. Though the problem that led to questions was the same, they are quite different. Even formulation

Comment: Indeed, not the same question. This one is an X-Y problem because you didn't understand what you did before, commented under your actual question.